# How to use the get_tld library for an entire column in dataset?

Tags: python, tld

This is the get_tld code:

```
from tld import get_tld
res = get_tld("http://toystory.disney.com/toy-story", as_object=True)
print(res.domain)
```

I'd like to apply this to an entire column in a dataset. I'm only interested in the top level domain and not the subdomain nor the suffix.

Comment: Which dataset ? In which structure ?

Comment: any dataset. I have a column full of url's. The column is df['homepage']

Comment: yes but the structure : dataframe, list, dict matters

Comment: It's a list of dtype: object

Comment: Does the answer helps you ? Is true, consider accepting/voting it up ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Series.apply()`

```
df['tld'] = df['homepage'].apply(lambda x: get_tld(x, as_object=True).domain)
```